# Node js stream is pending

Tags: node.js, download, streaming

I have the following `node` route:

```
router.route('/resource/:encodedString/:mediaType')
.all(function (req, res) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.params.encodedString, require('../secret')());
    var mediaObject = decoded.mediaObject;

    res.header('content-disposition', 'filename="' + mediaObject.fileName + req.params.mediaType + '"');
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(mediaObject.targetDir + mediaObject.fileName + req.params.mediaType);
    res.pipe(stream);
})
```

Which is called by my client.

However this does not give me the result i want because once this is called the response is pending.

```
    Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:http://localhost/myProject/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
```

Resulting in the content not displaying.

So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not ending your response, that's why it's pending. My suggestion is to call `res.end()` on the `end` event of your readable stream, like:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(mediaObject.targetDir + mediaObject.fileName + req.params.mediaType);
res.pipe(stream);

stream.on('end', function () {
  console.log("Reading operation completed.");
  res.end();
});;
```

Comment: sadly this did not resolve the issue still pending. Also the end function is never called

Comment: Also pipe should do this operation behind the scene

Comment: Could you put a `console.log("something")` inside the `data` event, just to make sure the file is being read? And in the `error` event too.

Comment: i found that the stream actually works however my video player is not able to play the video do you know why that might be? (if i right click and save the video the stream is called correctly and the video is downloaded)

Comment: On thing that I missed: you should pipe the readable stream `stream` to the writable stream `res`, so it should be `stream.pipe(res)`, right?